# Is $HTTP_XXX_VARS different from $_XXX in PHP?

Tags: php

Does the following code make sense?:

```
$t_server = isset( $_SERVER ) ? $_SERVER : $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
```

As I understand, `$HTTP_XXX_VARS` is same with `$_XXX`, except `$HTTP_XXX_VARS` is deprecated. Thus, I don't understand the code above.

Is there a case that two variables are different in an old system in which `$HTTT_XXX_VARS` is not considered as deprecated?

Comment: In PHP3 and earlier, $_SERVER did not exist. So, this code apparently wants to be functional on very old PHP installs.

Comment: @kainaw : good assumption, but isset() has arrived in PHP4. Probably the author of this line has read the docs too fast =)

Comment: @Jeon : so, if you want to correct this line, you can. This will have no incidence. The docs don't speak about any differences from a version to another, also the comments. This is just a variable renaming to be more consistent with the other superglobals' nomenclature.

Comment: My answer is: delete that code, it is outdated - no need to worry about that anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` and [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) are different variables (if both are set). They initially contain the same values but, being different, the changes that the script does on one of them do not affect the other.

The [`superglobals`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER` etc) were introduced on `PHP 4.1`. The long named variables (`$HTTP_GET_VARS`, `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` etc) were deprecated on `PHP 4.1`  and they were removed on `PHP 5.4`.

`PHP 5.0` introduced the configuration setting [`register_long_arrays`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays) that was used to tell `PHP` to create (or not) the old long-named variables (`$HTTP_GET_VARS` and the rest). The setting was deprecated on `PHP 5.3` and removed altogether on `PHP 5.4` (together with the long-named arrays).

As you can see, between `PHP 4.0` and PHP `5.4` one or both versions of these variables were available to the programmer.

The line:

```
$t_server = isset( $_SERVER ) ? $_SERVER : $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
```

takes advantage of the new superglobal variable `$_SERVER`, if available (on `PHP >= 4.1`), but it falls back to the old `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` if it runs on older `PHP`. It was probably written years ago, while `PHP 4` was still in use on a lot of servers.

Except on the unlikely case when you are stuck with `PHP 4.0`, you can safely change the above line to:

```
$t_server = $_SERVER;
```

or just use `$_SERVER` instead of `$t_server` everywhere.