# PHP 7.4 to 8.0 - Errors (Trying to access array offset)

Tags: php, error-handling, isset

We just updated to PHP 8.0 from 7.4 and are getting a bunch of errors that I'm working through.

One of the errors is actually 2 errors that looks like this:

```
Warning: Undefined variable $HTTP_SERVER_VARS in /home/mxst1k/public_html/includes/functions.inc.php on line 123

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/mxst1k/public_html/includes/functions.inc.php on line 123
```

In this case, line 123 is the second row in the snippet of code below:

```
if (!isset($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['REQUEST_URI'] = $HTTP_SERVER_VARS["PHP_SELF"];
    if (isset($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['QUERY_STRING']) && $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['QUERY_STRING']!='') {
        $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
}
```

I've been trial and error fixing some of the other warnings and errors, but this is from a functions include file and I don't want to mess it up!  I believe I may need to do something with Isset here, but it's a little fuzzy for me.

Any insight on the fix here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` this may be a constant , no need for the $

Comment: I'd be very surprised that was working in 7.4. $HTTP_SERVER_VARS was deprecated and removed in 5.4.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989005/is-http-xxx-vars-different-from-xxx-in-php

Comment: https://blog.tigertech.net/posts/php-5-3-http-server-vars/ has some information on how to switch your code to use the proper variables, and https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php gives you the details of each one.

Comment: @aynber I think you're right, but this problem would have presented notices rather than warnings in 7.4. I assume that's why it only became obvious after updating to 8.

Comment: Make a backup and/or test this before maybe breaking your app: `find /path/to/app/dir -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/\$HTTP_SERVER_VARS/$_SERVER/g'` but also if you were previously running this app on 7.x and simply ignoring the notices, then even if it works perfectly you're going to re-activate potentially _vast_ swaths of code that was simply skipped until now.

Comment: @aynber, your suggestion put me on the right track.  Had some $HTTP_SERVER_VARS that I changed to $_SERVER and it seemed to fix the problem.  Thanks....do you want to post the answer so I can accept it?